# Sql full text search for 'c' in a candidate table

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have found this on microsoft support ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547(v=SQL.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)) :

```
SELECT candidate_name,SSN FROM candidates WHERE CONTAINS(candidate_resume,”SQL Server”)
```

Is it possible to call the script with "c" (candidate that have learned C language)?

Because c is single character, it doesn't work with fulltext search. Only if I set stoplist to off as following, the script returns data:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [ADNEOM.BE].[adneom].[T_CANDIDATE] SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

But the data returned include c# and c++ too, and I want only C. 
In addition, I don't think that disable system stoplist is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

From technical point of view, I see nothing that prevents you from doing a fulltext search on "c" character, except for minimal pattern length threshold mentioned in the question, so the answer is **Yes, it is possible**.

I assume that `candidate_resume` is a text field and `like` operator is applicable, so you may consider another solution:

```
select candidate_name, SSN from candidates where candidate_resume like '%C%';
```

But, before doing that you should consider that searching by one letter will give you tons of false-positive results. For example, my answer contains it 14 times.

If you have detailed wanted and unwanted patterns list, you can add it to the query:

```
--positive cases list
... where (candidate_resume like '%c/%' or candidate_resume like '%c,%' or ... 

--negative cases list
...) and candidate_resume not like '%C#% and candidate_resume not like '%mvc% and ...
```

Disclaimer: Having lots of such clauses will slow down your query.

Disclaimer: Maybe you'll need "%c/%", not '%c/%', I don't remember unfortunately. In that case feel free to edit my post or add a comment so I fix it.

Comment: Because the format in resume file is generally same, I know that this skills appears as 'c/...', 'c,..' or '...,c'. Is it possible to check only those occurences (and not 'C#', 'mvc'...)?

Comment: Sure, if you have defined set of wanted and unwanted patterns, you can add them. See detailed example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, for text field, your solution is good. For another column format (binary) is it possible to use contains or containsTable with patterns?

Comment: @user1845394 I think yes, but the concern about performance is still here, and probably even worse. The last is my guess actually :)